# Auth0 Universal Login Experience sign-up hook

Tags: auth0

I'm using the Auth0 New Universal Login Experience and need to create a record in my application database when a new user signs up.  How/where can I hook into the sign-up processes to trigger some post sign-up code?

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to `Hooks` in the dashboard, and click `+ Create New Hook` then select `Post User Registration`, you can configure your hook there.